# Ember 2.4 change main view css class

Tags: css, ember.js

I'm looking for a way to change the css classname of the root element of an Ember app in Ember 2.4.

The old way doesn't work anymore because of deprecation, and now I have :

```
<body class="ember-application">
   <div id="ember414" class="ember-view">
     <!-- THE WHOLE APP -->
   </div>
</body>
```

I'm looking for making something like :

```
<body class="ember-application">
   <div id="ember414" class="ember-view theCssClass">
     <!-- THE WHOLE APP -->
   </div>
</body>
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Answer (score 2):

Fear not, the deprecated functionality is still available as [ember-legacy-views](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-legacy-views).

```
ember install ember-legacy-views
ember g view application
```

Then add your class to the generated view:

```
classNames: ['woot']
```

PS This might change when Ember introduces routable components.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

Css selector '.ember-view:first-of-type' or 'body'.

You could also insert a wrapper in your application.hbs file:

```
<div class="your-style">
  <!-- Other content -->
  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Pretty sure this works.

Comment: No, this doesn't solve the problem. I need to set a CSS rule on the whole app.

Comment: @pierred69 did you find a solution?